# Using modified mongoose-uuid2 breaks save operation

Tags: node.js, mongoose, uuid

So, I have been battling a problem with nested UUID's in mongoose that is outlined in the following stack overflow post

[Mongoose and array of ref UUID's does not convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56494736/mongoose-and-array-of-ref-uuids-does-not-convert/57537322?noredirect=1#comment101692681_57537322)

However, after some more testing and research, I found that this breaks another part of my code for updates to documents that I use to apply to the system. Since this code is complex, I will provide an simpler example that creates this same condition.

Upon installing the following nodejs packages

> "mongoose": "^5.6.10", 
>   "mongoose-uuid2": "^2.3.0", 
>   "uuid": "^3.3.3",
>   "uuid-mongodb": "^2.1.1"

Then, updating the mongoose-uuid2 index.js file as outlined in the previous post.

and finally setting up the following code that demonstrates the problem:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var uuid = require("uuid-mongodb");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
require('mongoose-uuid2')(mongoose);
var UUID = mongoose.Types.UUID;

var TestISchema = Schema({
  _id: { type: UUID, default: uuid.v4, required: true },
  name: { type: String, required: true }
}, { id: false, toObject: {
  "getters": true,
  "virtuals": true,
  "transform": function(doc, ret, options) {
    delete ret._id;
    return ret;
  }
}, toJSON: {
  "getters": true,
  "virtuals": true,
  "transform": function(doc, ret, options) {
    delete ret._id;
    return ret;
  }
} });

var TestIISchema = Schema({
  _id: { type: UUID, default: uuid.v4, required: true },
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  testIs: [{ type: UUID, ref: 'Product' }]
}, { id: false, toObject: {
  "getters": true,
  "virtuals": true,
  "transform": function(doc, ret, options) {
    delete ret._id;
    return ret;
  }
}, toJSON: {
  "getters": true,
  "virtuals": true,
  "transform": function(doc, ret, options) {
    delete ret._id;
    return ret;
  }
} });

TestIISchema.virtual("id").get(function() {
  return uuidv4.from(this._id).toString();
});

TestIISchema.virtual("id").set(function(uuid_string) {
  this._id = uuid.from(uuid_string);
});

TestISchema.virtual("id").get(function() {
  return uuid.from(this._id).toString();
});

TestISchema.virtual("id").set(function(uuid_string) {
  this._id = uuidv4.from(uuid_string);
});

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', {useNewUrlParser: true});

var TestIModel = mongoose.model('TestI', TestISchema);
var TestIIModel = mongoose.model('TestII', TestISchema);

console.log(`Creating a new Test I document`);
var mytestI = new TestIModel({ "name": "testproduct"});

console.log(`Saving a Test I document`);
mytestI.save().then(() => {
  console.log(`Getting all of Test I documents`);
  return TestIModel.find({});
})
.then((results) => { 
  console.log(`Assigning Test I documennt ID's to an Test II document`);
  var testIuuids = [];
  results.forEach((result) => {
    testIuuids.push(result.id);
  });
  mytestII = new TestIIModel(
    { 
      "name": "testIIproduct", 
      "testIs": testIuuids 
    }
  );
  return Promise.resolve(mytestII);
})
.then((doc) => {
  console.log(`Saving Test II`);
  return doc.save();
})
.then((result) => {
  console.log(result);
  console.log(`Getting Test II by id ${result.id}`);
  return TestIIModel.findById(result.id);
})
.then((document) => {
  document.name = "testIIproduct2";
  document.testIs = []
  return document.save();
})
.then((result) => {
  console.log(result);
})
.catch((error) =>{
  console.log(error);
  mongoose.disconnect();
});
```

Upon installing and executing the following error occurs on the last save.

> Path `_id` is required.

Upon troubleshooting and running it through the debugger I can see the code going through the updated patched code and if I remove the updated code that is outlined in the previous post for mongoose-uuids it works. However, my previous problem that is outlined in that post comes back. I also tried removing the "required: true" on line 8 and 27 on the schema, and this produced another error on line 96 findById:

> No document found for query "{ _id: \'eacdf837-ee2c-4c61-9271-744234b67868\' }

I also tried changing line 96 findById to TestIIModel.find({"id": result.id}), however the Model could not find the document.

My apologies for the large post but I could not find a way to recreate this issue without all of this information. Also as a background, using UUID's in this manner is a requirement. I am stumped by this, so any assistance in this matter would be appreciated.